# Cannot toggle between Shared/Final layout in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor

In experience editor for my site, the shared/final toggle is disabled.  I am on Sitecore 8.1 update 3.

I have already set the `Preview.ResolveSite` setting to `true`.  Are there any additional steps or considerations for enabling this feature?

Comment: Hi Dylan
I have had a similar issue recently and I had to set the Preview.ResolveSite to true and recycle the app pool to see it working. Did you try recyling? Also I'm assuming you can see Preview.ResolveSite showing up on the showconfig page?

Comment: Hey Diego, turns out it was an extra site hanging out in my site definition that caused the issue.  After removing it, the feature became active again.  Not really sure why but I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: great and thanks for sharing the solution as well

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue for anyone else who comes across this:

I had 5 sites all setup to resolve to the same path within the content tree as part of my multi-lingual strategy.  I recently removed two of the sites, but didn't fully remove them by accident (site definition was still there, as well as some events like cache clearing on publish).  After fully removing the two extra sites, the shared/final toggle was re-enabled.

Hope this helps someone in the future.